# C++ Visual Studio Code: Debugging terminates with NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I am having some problems with debugging C++ in Visual Studio Code.

It crashes with `NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object` if I try to look into a certain variable.

At first I thought it might be because this variable is declared `const` and so the compiler might compile it away but other `const`-variables are fine (I also use `-g -O0`).

This is my launch.json:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "g++ build and debug active file",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/build/src/build_optimizer",
            "args": [ ],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/build/src",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ],
            "miDebuggerPath": "gdb"
        }
    ]
}
```

I googled and it appears this error was quite common two to three years ago but it supposedly was fixed in the Visual Studio C++ extension.

I already deleted the extension and re-installed it. Deleted my CMake build-folder etc.

Any ideas what could cause this issue?

This is the variable which causes trouble:

```
const std::unordered_map<Item, int32_t> missing_items = Utility::get_missing_items(goal_pair, goal_recipe, initial_items);
```

with:

```
std::unordered_map<Item, int32_t> Utility::get_missing_items(const std::pair<Item, int32_t>& goal_item, const Recipe& recipe,
                                                             const std::unordered_map<Item, int32_t> &current_items) {
    
    std::unordered_map<Item, int32_t> return_map;

    /* do things */

    return return_map;
}
```

I don't see a way how this could be null. Even if it were null, shouldn't Visual Studio Code just display it as nullptr?

Comment: The problem is probably at the calling point to Utility::get_missing_items().  One of the object passed by reference is a dereferrnced nullptr, maybe?

Comment: @MichaëlRoy No, I can look at any of them in a debug session. It just breaks at `missing_items`.